# Setup time Metrics for Webservice Call

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, post, soap

I am calling a webservice to send json data by post method. Here is the code for that:

```
string sample_url = "mywebservice/createsample;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sample_url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
CookieCollection cookcol = new CookieCollection();
cookcol.Add(cookie);

string body= json data
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

postStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string satus = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
postStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(postStream);
```

I need to get some timestamp around this webservice request and response as the service seems quite slow. How do I put the countdown timer around this? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

// your code to measure here

sw.Stop();

// print sw.Elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you aren't testing your own network latency as well. If you are interested specifically in how long each service call takes, you should probably use a `Stopwatch` as per @nvoigt answer, but put this round your service implementation method.